# dotnet publish AOT Precompiling failed

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I am using AOT in .NET 8 p6. We have a staging environment where the code compilation fails with this error:

```
wasmApp.Native.targets(651,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\vsagent\_work\1\s\..\obj\Release\net8.0\wasm\for-publish\aot-in\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll with exit code -1073741819
```

The exact same code compiles successfully when using Azure DevOps Hosted compilation. Also ~1/20 ("sometimes") the staging environment successfully compiles the code.

What could be wrong in our Staging server? I have tried to increase the page file if the RAM is an issue but didn't seem to work. Any tips?